# Use of AND and OR in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to access records from SQLite in android using `rawQuery(query,arg)`. I have two columns in database one called `friendsID` and 2nd called `emailSenderID`.

Now If I send mail to my friend `emailSenderID`-column will save my ID and `friendsID`-column save my friend's ID. If I receive an email from same friend then `friendsID`-column will save my ID and `emailSenderID`-column will save my friend's ID.

Now, If I wanna fetch record like this:

```
Select * from emailTable where friendsID =fID 
and emailSenderID=fID 
OR emailSenderID=myID
```

Please guide me how I can use `AND` and `OR` operators for Android SQLite.

Comment: You probably need to use brackets `(` and `)` to group your conditions together properly. Please consider working on your explanation and formatting...this is really hard to decipher.

Comment: What's the problem you are solving?

Comment: @Till Helge Helwig thanks,I try to modify as much as I can.@Sean Owen I want to fetch data from SQLite with multiple AND and OR in where condition . .

Comment: AND and OR function exactly the same way they do in any programming language and you can group them for complex conditionals.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this: "Get me all entries from `emailTable` where `friendsID` is `fID` and `emailSenderID` is either `fID` or `myID`." In that case you need to group it like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM emailTable WHERE friendsID=fID AND 
     (emailSenderID=fID OR
     emailSenderID=myID)
```